# Trying to understand print_r() return

Tags: php, soap, return

I have a variable defined like this :

`$result = $soap_client->CompanycodeGetlist($params);`

`print_r($results);`

Please can some one help me to understand the return of the print_r($results) ?

```
stdClass Object ( [CompanycodeList] => stdClass Object ( [item] => Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [CompCode] => 0001 [CompName] => SAP A.G. ) [1] => stdClass Object ( [CompCode] => 01 [CompName] => Debussy ) [2] => stdClass Object ( [CompCode] => 02 [CompName] => Ravel )
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated i'm confused...

Comment: If you just mean what is the output its an object http://us3.php.net/manual/en/language.types.object.php if the return of CompanycodeGetlist is an object print_r is just printing it.

Comment: yes its an object but is it an object called CompanycodeList and in this object there is another object called item and so on ?

Comment: The only explanation of that is the return of CompanyCodeList is an object of its own name. If you try `var_dump($results)` and get the same response that is the response of the function.

Answer (score 0):

$results is an object with a CompanycodList property that is also an object with an item property that is an array....

try

```
echo "<pre>";
print_r($results);
echo "</pre>";
```

to get more intelligibly formatted results.